# Multinomial distribution and conditional probability

Tags: probability

> An urn contains $w$ white, $b$ black and $r$ red balls. $n$ extractions with replacement are made. $X_w$, $X_b$ and $X_r$ are the random variables representing the number of white, black and red balls extracted. I need to find $\mathbb{P}(X_w=a,X_b=b\mid X_r=c)$, where $a+b+c=n$.

Each probability is $p_w=\displaystyle\frac{w}{w+b+r}$,$p_b=\displaystyle\frac{b}{w+b+r}$ and $p_r=\displaystyle\frac{r}{w+b+r}$, so I guess the answer is:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_w=a,X_b=b\mid X_r=c)=\dfrac{(n-c)!}{{a!}{b!}}\left(\dfrac{p_w}{p_w+p_b}\right)^a\left(\dfrac{p_b}{p_w+p_b}\right)^b$$

Comment: You can get proper spacing by using `\mid` instead of `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct result when $a+b+c=n$. To be precise, you should mention that this probability is zero otherwise. Also, you could write the factorial factor as $\binom{n-c}a$. Also, you don't need the detour through the probabilities; since their denominators cancel, you can just as well write

$$
\mathbb{P}(X_w=a,X_b=b\mid X_r=c)=\binom{n-c}a\left(\frac w{w+b}\right)^a\left(\frac b{w+b}\right)^b\;.
$$

Which brings us to an error in the problem statement: The variable $b$ has been used twice. (Presumably the intended meaning wasn't that all black balls are drawn.)